# Including external libraries in lambda python functions

Tags: aws-lambda

Is it still the case that I have to upload a zip and can't use the in-line code editor to include external libraries for python lambdas?  I can include externals with node in-line, hoped they had added that ability for python lambdas.

Comment: The premise is wrong. Python behaves and behaved identical to node. You can upload a zip with code and if the zip is small enough you can then edit the code inline. If the zip is too large you can't. Unrelated to language, unrelated to external libraries. And both supports Layers to package libraries separately.

Comment: yeah i got confused, node google cloud functions can have a package.json in the editor so u dont need to upload anything to get it to load external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only libraries that are present in the Lambda runtime are those for the AWS SDK. All other libraries, regardless of programming language, need to be deployed with your application. However, if you need to use a particular library with several different Lambda functions, you can deploy a [Lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) and run your functions on top of the same layer.

Comment: lol ive been doing too much multi-cloud, u can do this in node google cloud functions without uploading anything, not node aws lambda, got confused

Comment: No worries, it can be confusing at times. :)